# Duda con precision de Double en java

Tags: java, double

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y me he encontrado con un problema que no logro entender por mas que he leido acerca de eso. Se trata de la precision con double.
Explicando un poco mejor les comento:
En una pequeña práctica me pareció curioso hacer un metodo que le pasara dos parámetros, uno decimal y el otro entero. Lo que debe hacer el método es elevar n veces el numero 10 y luego multiplicarlo por un número décimal. Lo que me intriga es que hice dos metodos para obtener el mismo resultado, uno con recursividad y el otro con un bucle, pero para mi sorpresa es que cuando envío por ejemplo (2.55, 2) el resultado debe ser 255. Para mi sorpresa que al resolverlo con recursividad me da exacto 255, mientras que cuando lo hago con un bucle el resultado es 254.99999999999997. Alguien podría explicarme por que es la diferencia, si estoy ocupando los mismos tipos?

```
public double multiplicarPorDiez(double n, int m){
    if(m==-1){
        return 1;
    } else if(m==1){
        return n*multiplicarPorDiez(n,m-1);
    }else {
        return 10*multiplicarPorDiez(n,m-1);
    }
}
public double multiplicarDiez(double n, int m){
    double diez=10;
    for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
        diez*=diez;
    }
    return n*diez;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a ver si me acuerdo del tema de conversiones numéricas en computadoras, el problema de la perdida de precisión se debe a la manera de representar los números que usan los ordenadores, los humanos usamos una notación decimal y los ordenadores usan notación binaria, esto quiere decir que cuando tu ingresas en un ordenador el número 26 el ordenador automáticamente lo transforma a binario quedando en 0001 1010, el problema de estas transformaciones es que de vez en cuando perdemos precisión en según que operaciones, si te interesa el tema puedes ampliar la información [aquí](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=960:java-redondear-a-2-o-mas-decimales-errores-precision-bigdecimal-roundingmode-biginteger-cu00907c&catid=58&Itemid=180). Ahi te ofrecen la posibilidad de corregir el asunto de la perdida con bigdecimal que no es más que otro tipo de numero con mucha mas precision que el double.

Como cosa curiosa resulta que multiplicar y dividir en decimal es mucho mas dificil que en binario ya que si yo quiero multiplicar en decimal debo aprenderme demasiadas cosas, tablas de multiplicar e historias de calculo, pero para dividir o multiplicar en binario es hasta un juego de niños. Cojamos por ejemplo el numero que te he comentado en binario 0001 1010 es en decimal 26 si queremos multiplicar por 2 ese numero binario simplemente corriendo losdigitos una posicion a la izquierda tenemos el 26 x 2 = 52 => 0011 0100, siendo la division por dos la misma operacion pero en sentido contrario. Es fascinante el mundo de las matemáticas y mucho mas el de la computacion.

Comment: Gracias por responder... interesante respuesta... pero lo que no logro comprender por que en el ejemplo de los dos métodos que puse, el recursivo es mas preciso que el otro, si es el mismo tipo de datos que uso